# Which reading of 通って is correct in this sentence?

Tags: readings, collocations

**Question Part 1**: Which reading of 通って is correct in this sentence?

もっともっと学校【がっこう】に通【??】って、絵【え】を勉強【べんきょう】したかった

*I wanted to go to school more and study painting.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/kyoiku/kyoiku/news/20221108-OYT1T50135/

According to the wwwjdic definitions (here in shortened form):

通る【とおる】 go by

通う【かよう】 go to and from

However, at least one example in goo seems to contradict the first definition, since the example refers to buses that "go to and from":

駅とお寺の間にバスが通っている

*Buses run between the station and the temple.*

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/通る/#je-53849](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8B/#je-53849)

**Question Part 2**: Is the reading of "to go to school" (in the sense of "to attend school regularly") always 学校【がっこう】に通【かよ】う?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:** It is かよ(って) and **Q2:** yes, 学校に通う is always かよう and never とおる.

とおる basically means *to pass through* and takes を-phrase. So 学校**を**通{とお}る would mean you enter the site of a school and go out from the other side (e.g. for a shortcut). Here 学校 is just an object on your path and not something you attend.